# Sitecore add here button not showing the Add rendering dialog

Tags: sitecore, experience-editor

All of a sudden the `Add here` button in experience editor to add a rendering is not working. When clicked nothing happens. Do you have any idea where can I start look into? I already tried to remove the custom styles and scripts in my Editing theme. Sitecore version is `9 update 2` and SXA is `1.7`

Answer (score 0):

You have started from the right thing. Please make sure that you have the valid base themes defined in the Media Library: */sitecore/Media Library/Base Themes*, especially, the *Editing Theme* with the logic used to edit components in Experience Editor.

Another idea is to check the order in which the layers load in Sitecore. The default order is defined in *Website/App_Config/layers.config*, make sure that SXA configuration loads last in the Modules layer, so that all custom modules are processed ahead of the SXA. It is recommended to create a custom patch file instead of modifying the standard configuration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the console?
Maybe you have some error caused by some new custom script and that's preventing the add button to work

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue for a specific set of placeholders, fortunately affecting only a single project in our solution. To fix the behavior, we had to manually set "editable" to false -> save item and then back to true -> save item for every affected placeholder.

**[EDIT]**
We finally found the culprit, it was related to a Sitecore bug documented here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/706490

Setting the value for Query.MaxSize from 100 to 400 permanently fixed the issue